How to change colors of borders of OTP Text field widget in flutter? changing through OTPfieldStyle not working?
 OTPTextField(
                  length: 5,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  fieldWidth: 30,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: gettcolor(context)),
                  textFieldAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  fieldStyle: FieldStyle.box,
                  onCompleted: (pin) {
                    otp = pin;
                  },
                ),

No matter if i use otpfieldstyle and set color to anything its remain the same

which exactly package do you use?

Try to set the following attributes:
OTPTextField(

otpFieldStyle: OtpFieldStyle(focusBorderColor: Colors.amber,), // focused border color
borderColor: Colors.purple, // enabled border color

),

If the above attributes didn't worked
Then, You should warp your OTPTextField with Theme Widget and set data (TextField Decoration) to override the default visual properties.
Hope it helps you.
